# Get Exception Message from "Item Added" Event Receiver in JQuery Ajax Cal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, sharepoint-2010

I am updating a list item using REST with Ajax call(Asyn:True).
and An Event Receiver will be triggered after updating.
Ajax call is waiting until even receiver is completed, but I want to see the exception in Ajax error function, if there is any exception in Event Receiver.
Is it possible?

```
ajax({
    url: restSource,
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.ListItem' }, 'Columns1': 'Value'
    }),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
        "If-Match": "*"
    }, 

    success: function (data) {
            waitDialog.close();
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Something went wrong")
       //Want to read the exception from event receiver.
    }
```

Comment: your alert doesn't ending statement. `alert("Something went wrong")` semicolon should be there

Comment: @Vasim may have a look at automatic semicolon insertion. the code is fine, karteek may try console.log(data) inside of the error function ...

Comment: @Jonasw thank you I didn't idea about that.